# GDPR Compliance: Does this apply to JavaScript Web Storage?

Tags: javascript, privacy, web-storage

As far as I can see the main issue with GDPR and cookies is that cookies may be tracked and the data may be shared against user’s wishes.

The JavaScript Web Storage API is a useful repository for settings and other user data, but this doesn’t leave the browser.

Would using Web Storage require user permissions?

Comment: _“but this doesn’t leave the browser”_ - not implicitly of course; but it could easily be send back to the server explicitly, for example via an AJAX request. So at least it allows to assign multiple unconnected requests to the same user resp. client browser.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a legal, not a programming, question.

Comment: @CBroe That could apply to any activity, so that would imply that JavaScript itself requires permission.

Comment: @Manngo well any data storage/tracking does, more or less. What specific techniques are used is rather secondary. I’m a bit baffled myself that the focus mainly seems to be on cookies almost anywhere you look. But since almost any data protection statement/privacy policy update I have seen so far, even the ones generated with the help of lawyers, still goes with the “Cookies are small _text files_ stored on your computer” nonsense, I have given up on expecting any technical expertise behind this …

Answer (score -1):

Any data related to the user is under control by GDPR.
You should ask the user for that.